# PhantomJS was placed in path and can execute in terminal, but PATH error in Python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

note: PhantomJS runs in PyCharm environment, but not IDLE

I have successfully used PhantomJS in Python in the past, but I do not know what to do to revert to that set up.

I am receiving this error in Python (2.7.11): selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.

I have tried to 'symlink' phantomjs to the path (usr/local/bin [which is also in the path]), and even manually locate /usr/local/bin to place phantomjs in the bin folder. However, there is still a path error in python.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you permissions to execute it from the `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`?

Comment: You can try first passing the path when you initialise,if that does not work then you have other problems

Comment: What does Python think the path is?  Look at `os.environ['PATH']`: chances are it is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After placing phantomjs in the folder /usr/bin, the application ran successfully. To access the folder directly, open a finder window, click 'Go' menu at top of screen, click 'Go to folder...', enter '/usr/bin'. Note that if on Mac OS El Capitan or newer, there is a default restriction to this folder which [can be disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by passing the `executable_path` keyword arg to the driver constructor. For example:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Path/to/driver/phantomjs")
```

Note that this must be the driver file itself, not the folder which contains it.

Thanks to [PhantomJS() not running in pyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464924/phantomjs-not-running-in-pycharm) for hinting at this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Download - http://phantomjs.org/download.html

/usr/bin is restricted on Mac, but putting /bin/phantomjs in /usr/local/bin works

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to execute in Terminal, just restart PyCharm and it will synchronize the environment variables from the system. (You can check in "RUN" => "Edit Configurations")