# PhantomJS() not running in pyCharm

Tags: python, phantomjs, pycharm

Hi I am trying to PhantomJS() in pyCharm IDE using

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

I have also tried

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "/Path")
```

But every time it gives me error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH
```

But this is running absolutely fine in Python 3.6.0 Shell. I have also set the path varible correctly--"C:\PhantomJs\bin\phantomjs\".

What could be the problem in pyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out the problem.
In the executable path instead of using C:\PhantomJs\bin\phantomjs\ I used
C:/PhantomJs/bin/phantomjs/. That is reversing the slashes solves the problem.

Comment: Most likely the problem is because \ in a string escapes the next character. If you want to use backslashes, you need to escape them: `'C:\\PhantomJs\\bin\\phantomjs\\'`.